# Why are my get methods always returning 0

Tags: java

I'm creating this program which will print a calendar of a date inputted by a user. In my method `dayOfWeek()` the formula takes day month and two types of year and calculates a number between 0-6 which is equal to a day of the week.
However my method always returns 2 and after some testing I found that none of the get methods (`getDay()`, `getMonth()`, `getYear())` are returning values.

A command line input is "dd/mm/yyyy" which is split up into the main. In the `dayofweek()` method it is returning 2 always or Monday (because it is the value assigned to 2). however when defining the variables q, m, K and J they are all set to 0

Can anyone see the logic error? (Edit, some of the indenting is a bit off)

```
class MyCalendar
{
private MyDate myDate;
private Day day;
int dayofmonth, month, year;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String userinput = args[0];
    
    String[] splitdate = userinput.split("/");
    
    int dayofmonth = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[0]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[2]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[1]);
    if (month <= 2)
    {
        month = month + 12;
    }

    MyDate myDate = new MyDate(dayofmonth, month, year);
    MyCalendar mycal = new MyCalendar(myDate);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    
    while (myDate.isDateValid() == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Date is not valid. Please input a valid date: ");
        
        userinput = scanner.nextLine();
        
        splitdate = userinput.split("/");
        
        dayofmonth = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[0]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[1]);
        
        if (month <= 2)
        {
            month = month + 12;
        }
        
        myDate.isDateValid();
    }
    
    System.out.println(myDate.getDay() + " " + myDate.getMonth() + " " + myDate.getYear() + " " + mycal.dayOfWeek());
}
public MyCalendar(MyDate myDate)
{
    this.myDate = myDate;
}
public Day dayOfWeek()
{
    MyDate Date = new MyDate(dayofmonth, month, year);
    
    Day myDay = Day.Sunday;
    
    int q = Date.getDay();
    int m = Date.getMonth();
    int K = (Date.getYear()%100);
    int J = (Date.getYear()/100);
    
    int h = ((q + ((13*(m+1))/5) + K + (K/4) + (J/4) + 5*J)%7);
    
    System.out.println(h + " " + q + " " + m + " " + K + " " + J);
    
    if (h == 0){
        myDay = Day.Saturday;
        return myDay;
    }
    if (h == 1){
        myDay = Day.Sunday;
        return myDay;
    }
    if (h == 2){
        myDay = Day.Monday;
        return myDay;
    }
    if (h == 3){
        myDay = Day.Tuesday;
        return myDay;
    }
    if (h == 4){
        myDay = Day.Wednesday;
        return myDay;
    }
    if (h == 5){
        myDay = Day.Thursday;
        return myDay;
    }
    if (h == 6){
        myDay = Day.Friday;
        return myDay;
    }
    
    System.out.println(q + " " + m + " " + K + " " + J);
    
    return myDay;
}
public int weekOfMonth()
{
    int week = 0;
    return week;
}
public void printCalendar()
{
}
}




class MyDate
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
public MyDate(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are your inputs and outputs? What were you expecting and why?

Comment: A command line input is "dd/mm/yyyy" which is split up into the main. In the dayofweek() method it is returning 2 always or Monday (because it is the value assigned to 2). however when defining the variables q, m, K and J they are all set to 0

Comment: this declaration `int dayofmonth = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[0]);` is shadowing the class field `int dayofmonth, month, year;`, but to be honest you should just rely on the instance values and not create a new instance of `MyDate` in this method

Comment: Does that mean instead of having the var dayofmonth, month, year, just use the splitdate[...]?

Comment: Maybe change `mycal.dayOfWeek()` to be like `mycal.dayOfWeek(myDate)`

Comment: I end up just getting this error " method dayOfWeek in class MyCalendar cannot be applied to given types;"

Comment: Yeah a bit of thinking and development is required on your part.

Comment: i found the problem is that the variables dayofmonth, month and year are all 0 when being passed in. Why is that occuring?

Comment: You are overwriting the instance variable myDate with a local variable myDate set to Sunday. Also, Java coding conventions use a small letter to start variables and method name (date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets think this through:

1) The `MyDate` code is simple.  A constructor and getters.  No bugs there that I can see.

2) The `MyDate` instance is created and used like this:

```
    MyDate Date = new MyDate(dayofmonth, month, year);

    Day myDay = Day.Sunday;

    int q = Date.getDay();
    int m = Date.getMonth();
    int K = (Date.getYear()%100);
    int J = (Date.getYear()/100);
```

There are some egregious style errors here (`Date` should be `date` and so on) which make this hard to comprehend.  An experience Java programmer would do a double-take after seeing `Date.getDay()`.  But that is a red herring.

3) The real issue is where are the values of `dayofmonth`, `month` and `year` coming from?  Answer: they are declared as fields of `MyCalendar`.

```
   int dayofmonth, month, year;
```

4) Where are they initialized?  Answer: Nowhere!!  You appear to be trying to initialize them in the `main` method as follows:

```
   int dayofmonth = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[0]);
   int year = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[2]);
   int month = Integer.parseInt(splitdate[1]);
```

But look carefully!  You are actually declaring and initializing **local variables** ... not the instance fields of a `MyCalendar` instance.  So the information is not going to where your code needs it.

---

You need to *redesign* your code.  For example, ask yourself why does `MyCalendar` have both a `myDate` field AND separate `dayofmonth` , `month` and `year` fields?

Think through the information flows.

As @ScaryWombat aptly commented:

> Yeah ... a bit of thinking and development is required on your part.

(In theory, we could rewrite your code for you, but you will learn a whole lot more by doing it yourself.  Particularly the "thinking" part.)